# Custom validation of standard xml schema (xsd) type in .net

Tags: c#, .net, validation, xsd

The problem that I have is this:

1. I have a lot of XSD files generated by 3rd party to check the conformance of document types
2. They use standard types (namely `gYear` and `date`) without realizing their real restrictions
3. They also use hard-coded checks on their side that have more restrictions then these standard types used in XSD (i.e., spaces before or after the numbers for `gYear` are ok, but will fail on their side)
4. Changing schemas is really not a way to go (XSDs are numerous and being updated frequently)

So, here's the question: what can I do to enforce more strict rules to validate some of standard types?
I use .NET 3.5 (C#) and we have a wrapper around the standard `XmlReader`, so using 3rd party project isn't an option at all.
I thought about loading additional schema file with some pre-defined types that will extend/override needed types, *or* somehow catch the moment when the needed type is validating the node and I can peek at the value of said node, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Additional requirements: the validation process should be streaming (i.e. no `XmlDocument` et al).

Comment: Are you sending or receiving messages?

Comment: @hugh I'm sending user-generated content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as far as I can tell, there really isn't any simple solution to this problem.

The best I could have come up with, is to modify the schema upon reading it to put in cache.

I simply remove the `type="xs:gYear"` and add `<simpleType>` sub-element (if needed):

```
    <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="^(19|2\d)\d{2}$" />
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Luckily, we have the infrastructure to translate the validation errors to human-readable errors, so there shouldn't be a confusion about the differences between the actual schema and the validation errors for these elements.

Also, a big note goes to the fact that every single type in XML Schema has facet `whiteSpace` set to `collapse`, so you cannot inherit from more suitable types such as `gYear`, `short` or `decimal`.